# High memory usage with w3wp application pool IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis, memory, iis-7

I have a website application running in it's own application pool on IIS 7.0. The application is an ASP.NET MVC 3 website.

I have noticed the memory usage for this applications corresponding w3wp IIS worker service is quite high ( 800 MB, with some fluctuation ).

I am trying to diagnose the problem and have tried the following:

I have disabled output page caching for the website at IIS level and then recycled the application pool. This causes the w3wp process to restart. The memory usage for this process then slowly creeps up to around 800 MB, it takes around 30 seconds to do so. There are no page requests being handled at this time. When I restart the website from IIS the memory size of the process does not alter.

I have tried running a debug copy of the application from VS 2010, there are no problems with memory usage.

**Some ideas I have/questions are:**

Is this problem related to the websites code? - Given that the memory rockets before any page requests have been sent/handled, I would assume this is NOT a code problem?

The application built in MVC has no handling of caching written into it.

The website uses real-time displaying of data,  it uses ajax requests periodically, and is generally left 'open' for long periods of time.

Why does the memory usage rocket up after the application is recycled and no user requests are being sent? Is this because it is loading old cache information into it's memory from disk?

The application does NOT crash, I'm just concerned about the memory usage, it is not that big of a website...

Any ideas/help with getting to the bottom of this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just looked my server and my pools use 900-1000 MB Virtual size Memory, and 380 MB Working set. My sites run smooth with out problem for some years now, and I have checked the sites from all sides. My pool never recycles and the server runs until the next update continuously with 40% stable free physical memory.

**If your memory is not continuously growing, then this memory is the code plus the data that you set as static, const, the string, and the possible cache, inside your application.**

You can use [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) to see the working and the virtual size memory.

You can also think to run a profile against your code to see if you have any "memory leak" or other issue. Find one from google: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=asp.net+memory+profiler.

Comment: BTW - You will be at 40% stable because by default the processModel in IIS is limited to only use 60% of available memory.  You can change this via the processModel memoryLimit setting.

Comment: @ProVega Actually beside IIS, there is the ms sql server, and ms backup program. The ms backup program can eat all of the free memory making the system slow. Then the MS SQL server can also eat a lot of memory for cache, so I have setup the memory max limits. So I end up to have some free memory because I have check this.

Comment: also in app-pool's advance settings popup, setting Enable 32-Bit Applications to true also reduce memory usage. see this post for info http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/bugs-issues-/app-pool-memory-drastically-different-from-32-64-bit

Answer (score 18):

The best thing to do if you can afford to use a debugger is install the [Windows Debugging Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/hh852363) and use something like WinDbg and SOS.dll to figure out exactly what is it in memory.

once you've installed the tools then you can:

1. Launch Windbg.exe running elevated (as Administrator)
2. Use "File->Attach To Process" and choose w3wp.exe for the app you are trying to figure out. If you have many you can use Task Manager and add the command-line column to see the PID or use IIS Manager->Worker Processes to figure it out, and then choose that process in WinDBG.
3. run:
4. .loadby sos clr
5. !dumpheap -stat

At that point you should be able to see all types sorted by the most memory consumption so you can start with the ones at the bottom. (I would recommend exclude Strings, and Object since those are usually a side-effect and not the cause).
Use "!dumpheap -type type-here" to find the instances and use !gcroot for those to figure out why they are in memory, maybe due to a static field, or an event handler leaked, WCF channels not disposed, or things like that are common sources.

Answer (score 3):

It probably doesn't apply here but thought I would throw it in for good measure. Recently I had a problem where my memory would go right up and max out when it really could of cleaned up 80% of it. Problem: It thought it about 2 more gig than it actually did so the GC was quite lazy. (It was due to a VM ware bug -windows was reporting 8 Gig but physically there was only 6.4). See blog.http://www.worthalook.net/2014/01/give-back-memory/

Answer (score 0):

Something that might help: if you "rewrite" (open/save) the web.config , then your application will reset, you should monitor the memory usage from that point. If it keeps growing during usage, this could mean memory leak or insane caching. You might be able to identify which actions on your site lead to memory increase. During a long time the memory usage of an application should be stable.