# how much memory are used by loaded assemblies in Application web AppDomain

Tags: c#, asp.net

Dear programming experts,

I have 2 questions to optimize ASP.net web applicatons design:

1) How much memory are used by loaded assemblies in a AppDomain of an Application Web? Can i measure it?

2) When application starts, all assemblies in bin folder are loaded, can i load them when are needed instead? Do you think if that idea improves the system operation?

Thanks in advance,
Milton

Comment: Find a .NET profiler, read its manual, and then you can play with it and learn the memory usage in detail. Even Microsoft provides that in Visual Studio. Use any other tool is neither enough nor ituitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [process explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to see the physical and the virtual memory that your pools use.

Now left the assemblies on the bin to be managed by the asp.net it self.

[image]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.technet.microsoft.com/bb896653.processexplorer(en-us,MSDN.10).jpg))</sub>

To see programmatically the used memory: [Determine memory used by asp.net cache in shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830633/determine-memory-used-by-asp-net-cache-in-shared-hosting/10830834#10830834)

and a similar question: [High memory usage with w3wp application pool IIS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666356/high-memory-usage-with-w3wp-application-pool-iis-7/9666573#9666573)